# How to combine elements of a list

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, arraylist

I'm working in c#. I have a sorted List of structures. The structure has a DateTime object which stores month and year and an integer which stores a value. The list is sorted by date. I need to traverse the list and combine it so that I only have one instance of the structure per date.

For example:
My initial list would look like this:

```
{ (Apr10, 3), (Apr10, 2), (Apr10, -3), (May10, 1), (May10, 1), (May10, -3), (Jun10, 3) }
```

The resulting list should look like this:

```
{ (Apr10, 2), (May10, -1), (Jun10, 3) }
```

I'm looking for a simple / efficient solution.

The struct is:

```
struct CurrentTrade
{
    public DateTime date;
    public int dwBuy;
}
```

The list is:

```
private List<CurrentTrade> FillList
```

Comment: Mutable structs are evil.  Also, you shouldn't use the `dw` prefix.

Comment: @SLaks: __Im__ mutable struct are evil?... I hope that's a mistake on your end.

Comment: Addie, is it a class or a struct?

Comment: @zneak: Fixed.  I can't believe I wrote that.

Comment: @Henk Sorry about the typo! I meant to write struct in the code sample. Although it doesn't matter to me whether it's implemented as a class or struct.

Comment: @Addie:  Structs should be immutable, meaning that it should not be possible to change the value of an existing struct after it's created.  You should replace the fields with read-only properties and provide a constructor that takes them as parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var newList = (
    from trade in FillList
    group trade by trade.Date.Date into g
    select new CurrentTrade { date = g.Key, dwBuy = g.Sum(t => t.dwBuy) }
).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with LINQ. Can you recommend a site to familiarize myself with the syntax?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx should provide you with some basic facts.

Comment: Thanks for the LINQ intro. This is going to be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use LINQ:

If the list is sorted by dates, then all the items with the same dates are next to each other.  You can do something like this:

```
for ( int i = FillList.Count - 1; i >= 1; i-- ) {
    if ( FillList[i].date == FillList[i-1].date ) {
       FillList[i-1].dwBuy += FillList[i].dwBuy;
       FillList.RemoveElementAt( i );
    }
}
```

The LINQ solution is recommended though, if your .NET supports it.

If the input dates include the time component and you want to merge on the date, just change the if statement from:

```
if ( FillList[i].date == FillList[i-1].date )
```

to

```
if ( FillList[i].date.Date == FillList[i-1].date.Date )
```

Comment: This will not work. (The trades are at different times)   Also, it won't handle three trades on the same date correctly.

Comment: The statement does explicitly just states the Date (though in a DateTime), but it's trivial to change if time is included.

Comment: This is actually the approach I started with and ran into problems before I posted this question.

Comment: What problems are you running into?  I had a typo in my first edit - if you change the order of the for loop it should be fine.

Comment: The problem was with my approach not yours. Thanks for your help I went with the LINQ approach and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [LINQ statements](http://blogs.popart.com/2007/12/understanding-linq/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var result  = FillList.GroupBy(x => x.date)
                      .Select(g => new CurrentTrade { 
                          date = g.Key, 
                          dwBuy = g.Sum(x => x.dwBuy) 
                      })
                      .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

If CurrentTrade does contain a time component you should convert it to a date only DateTime object:

```
var result  = FillList.GroupBy(x => x.date.Date)
                      .Select(g => new CurrentTrade { 
                          date = g.Key, 
                          dwBuy = g.Sum(x => x.dwBuy) 
                      })
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on the code that is not shown in the OP. If CurrentTrade was constructed with, e.g. date = DateTime.Now.Date this will work. The sample data does not contain times at all so Larry and I just made an assumption based on the facts of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a `HashSet<T>`? HashSets can't contain the same object twice. That may however require you to reimplement the `GetHash` method in your `CurrentTrade` class.

(Something easy like `return Date.GetHashCode() ^ dwBug` could do it though.)